# An efficient database design for a simple forum using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, optimization

I am in the process of designing a database for forum functionality for my website.After doing some searching on SO and google, I have come up with the following design:
**User table**

```
Username : varchar(256)
Password : varchar(256)
```

**Threads table**

```
ThreadId  :  int
UserId    :  int, related to Users table
Title     :  varchar(255)
Date      :  timestamp, when a thread was created
```

**Posts table**

```
PostId   :   int
ThreadId :   int, related to Threads table
UserId   :   int, related to Users table
Date     :   timestamp, when post was made
Title    :   varchar(255) - post title (optional)
Body     :   text - the actual body of a post
```

Even though this serves my purpose, i can't help but think this is not very efficient, especially for selecting all the posts for a particular thread for which it would be necessary to traverse the entire table.

From the top of my head, i can think of a design where the **Users table** and **Threads table** remain as they are, but instead of having a single table for the **Posts table**,I create a **Posts table** for every user having the same name as the user.This way retrieving all the posts belonging to a thread is a lot more efficient,since all I need is the userid of the person who started the thread.With this info I search the table with the same name to retrieve all posts for the specific thread.But is it a good idea to make the number of tables I create directly dependant on the number of registered users?What i also want to know is, which one of these designs will scale better,will be easier to manage? Is there a better database design for my requirement?

Comment: Check out: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-create-a-phpmysql-powered-forum-from-scratch/ though obviously use PDO or mysqli instead

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your design looks basically correct.

This is a classic **"normalised"** data structure - exactly the kind of shape that relational databases are built for.  If you don't know about normal forms, but came up with this structure, then you clearly have a natural understanding of how relational databases work.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms

In order for PHP to avoid traversing the whole table, you should ensure that you **issue a SQL statement that selects only the records you're looking for**.  E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE ThreadId = ? ORDER BY Date
```

Your worry about the database having to traverse the whole table is fair and reasonable, though you can avoid this - this is a classic relational database problem that was solved when they first appeared as commercial products more than 30 years ago.

You can **create an INDEX on posts** that supports the SQL you are running.  In this case something along the lines of:

```
CREATE INDEX postThreadsIndex ON posts ( ThreadId, Date )
```

This index allows your database engine to **find the records you're selecting very quickly, without having to read the whole table**.  If you want to know how, read up on b-tree indexes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree

As I said earlier in the answer, this is exactly the kind of thing that relational databases were built for, and your design is solid and appropriate.

**Do not consider any alternatives - you got it right first time!**

But, for completion's sake - let's look at your suggested alternative.

You suggest splitting the Post table by User - this would mean the following:

- User "UserA" creates a thread - his initial post is stored in posts_UserA
- User "UserB" responds to the post - his post is storied in posts_UserB
- User "UserC" responds to the post - her post is storied in posts_UserC

In order to retrieve the full thread you now need to look in posts_UserA, posts_UserB and posts_UserC.

If these were the only three users, then you would need to look through all the data in these threee tables in order to find all the posts, and this would be equal to the number of records that *would* have been in the table posts in your original design.

You gain nothing.

If you had 1000 other users, you would have to also look in these other 1000 tables in order to find that they didn't have any records.

You still gain nothing.

You could add added another table to store which users had commented on which posts - and therefore which tables to look in, but now the solution starts to get complicated.

You *could* split the Post table by Thread - this would mean that all the posts where in a table based on the thread that they were made on.  This would probably be pretty good for selecting the posts on a single thread, but it would be awful for:
 - selecting all the posts made by a given user.
 - finding the most recent post regardless of thread.
 - finding all the posts made on a particular date.
 - anything else that did not involve a particular thread.

Basically, the alternative that you suggest *may* be more efficient for a very particular query, but it will almost always be extremely complicated for any other query.

**The original design is simpler for all queries and can be made to perform well by adding indexes.**

If you ever get to the point where your SQL performance is too slow because of the volume of data, then you can look at table partitioning, which does what you describe in an invisible way.  But to be honest you're unlikely to ever need it unless your site is extremely popular - and if that's the case then you'll probably have the cash to invest in a fundamentals of relational databases course at that point anyway...

Comment: even if i did create indices for posts,threadid it would still be inefficent(internally) as the php server would have to traverse the entire table to retrieve records for a paticular threadid, hence I came up with the second design.what are your thoughts on the second database design, not the first one?

Comment: No, PHP should not need to traverse the whole table as you'll select the records you want using SQL.  E.g. SELECT * FROM posts WHERE threadId = ?

Comment: sorry, sql will have to traverse the entire table right to find all entries with a specific threadid.How do think the following works internally?By traversing the entire table right? Even though SELECT * FROM posts WHERE threadId = ? , would do what i want it to,but it would be slower than the second database design right?

Comment: No, it wouldn't, if you used an index to support the selection you want.  The questions you are asking are fundamental to how relational databases work, and the problems were solved many many years ago.  I'll update my answer in order to be clearer...

Comment: I have updated my answer substantially - I hope this covers the bulk of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I am in a similair situation and it does indeed sound like this will bottleneck your database by having a post table that keeps growing. When this becomes the case one way I would try to solve it is to use horizontal data sharding. You could add the thread title to the post data and split it halfway alphabeticly(as an example you might think of a better way). This way you can have 1 database with a table for posts in threads starting with A to K and from L to Z, when one whould search for all posts belonging to a thread you can halve the work of said search by having your logic select the right database to search in and ignore the other one. When you have to search for posts on a general search term this however does not help at all. In my use case the highest data demand is for retrieving posts under a forum thread (and I think that is with forums in general) horizontal data-sharding seems like a good idea to me and one can expand into things like pagination to improve performance,